# How to use imagepicker.js on the dynamically added Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a function which will dynamically add the images in the page by using body onload=getImages() function.

The first problem is that i can not see the images on the HTML page, though they are present while i am using inspect element. 
Secondly the image-picker is unable to use the dynamic content.

The code is as under:

**function.js**

```
var imgData={
        "1": {
            "url": "img/pic1.png",
            "name": "pic1"
        },
        "2": {
            "url": "img/pic2.png",
            "name": "pic2"
        },
        "3": {
            "url": "img/pic3.png",
            "name": "pic3"
        }
}
function getImages(){

    for ( var i in imgData) {

        $('#cont').append($('<option data-img-src="'+imgData[i].url+'" data-img-label="Just an image!" value="'+i+'">'));

    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="cont" multiple="multiple" data-limit='4'>
</select>
```

[Image-picker.js](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) Kindly refer to this also.

Comment: The images are present when you inspect element or the variable is?

Comment: Could it be a problem with your load order? If you load Image-picker before changing the dom, image-picker needs to be initiated a second time to find those new images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you gave us, you need to call `.imagepicker()` on the container **after** the images have been added.

```
function getImages(){
    var container = $('#cont');
    for (var i in imgData) {
        container.append($('<option data-img-src="'+imgData[i].url+'" data-img-label="Just an image!" value="'+i+'">'));
    }
    container.imagepicker();
}
```

PS: I put the result of `$('#cont')` in a variable because it's actually a shortcut to a complex function that ends up scanning the DOM for the element with the right ID. In other words, it's a costly function and you should avoid putting it in a loop whenever possible.